# Login functionality in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication, session-variables

I'm having this project where I need to implement login functionality in my webpage. Everything function, like I have the code and I understand its implementation. I have used a static global variable to keep track of the logging in status. I'm not very keen on session variables. Thing is, my program doesn't seem to validate my login status properly even though my "MySQL" statement is correct I think. Any one knows a solution to this or how to work with session variables.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide some more details as well as your source code.

Comment: i agree with @manniL. Please give your source code and your exact problem.

Comment: keep calm and show your code :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I see that you're a new user. Please before asking read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. It gives details of how to ask a question. In your current state, I don't think you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all here that you should post your code and your exact problem.

Session in PHP:

Every page must be checked before opening through 'Your Controller'. This is an example to understanding how is works. controller.php:

```
class controller{

    //login
    public function login()
    {
        // start session  
        session_start();

        $_SESSION['userLoggedin'] == true;

        header('index.php');
    }

    //To check, if user logged in
    public function ifLogged()
    {
         session_start();

        if($_SESSION['userLoggedin'] != true)
        {
            controller::logout();
        }

    }

    //logout
    public function logout()
    {
        // delete session  
        session_destroy();

        unset($_SESSION['userLoggedin']);

        header('login.php');
    }

}
```

In your index.php you have to include your controller, to check if user has logged in or not.

index.php

```
require_once('controller.php');
controller::ifLogged();
```